# iOS Storyboard UISplitViewController Seque to Full Screen

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2, uisplitviewcontroller

iOS newbie question here.

I have a UITabBarController as my root controller with a UISplitViewController as a child. I want to storyboard seque(push) from the detail view of the splitviewcontroller to a full screen with the navigation and tab bar(as if the detail view were full screen). I'm guessing this can't be done from the interface builder and I'll need some custom code to do this, but I'm not sure where to start looking for how to do this. I've looked through apple documentation and can't find much on the topic. Any help/direction on how to go about this would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, a couple of things:
1. Per Apple's documentation, the UISplitViewController must be the root view controller if you are going to use it.
2. After you load the split view, if you want a full screen view controller, you display it modally, using the full screen.

Comment: Yes, but showing it modally you lose the navigation bar(s). There are plenty of apps out in the app store that have a UITabBarController as the root controller using a UISplitViewController. Furthermore, the interface builder makes it very simple to set that scenario up.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like you are simply trying to hide the left (master) view, is that correct?  And as far as the apps in the app store that have that, they usually have the tab bar inside of the split view, and when they don't, they either build their own version of the split view or use something like MGSplitViewController because apple will not approve an app with a UISplitViewController unless it is the root view controller.

Comment: Yes, I would really just like the detail view to fill the screen. So is the UISplitViewController requirement to be the root controller still the case with ios5?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure about that!  I just looked through the documentation and no longer see the requirement that it is the root view controller, so I'm guessing that it's okay now!  That being said, I would not use it if you want to hide the master view since that isn't supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a UISplitViewController, create your own Container View Controller so that you can remove the master view when needed.  Check the documentation for UIViewController under the section titled "Implementing a Container View Controller".

Another possibility is to use one of the UISplitViewController replacements which allow you to hide the master view even when you are in landscape mode.

MGSplitViewController is one that a lot of people use:  [Github link](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/)