# Observe event notifications sent to root view controller and forward them to child view controllers

Tags: ios, events, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uiwindow

I am working on an app that has `UISplitViewController`s inside a `UITabBarController` under iOS 6.

This used to be a "no no," but apparently it's [okay now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723163/ios-storyboard-uisplitviewcontroller-seque-to-full-screen)?

Regardless, in order to make rotations work correctly, I have to [forward events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734016/uisplitviewcontroller-doesnt-autorotate) from the root view controller to my child split view controllers.

I am currently doing this for several known events (willRotate..., etc). However, there is one delegate method of the split view controller that is still not firing.

**My question is this**: Is there a way to watch (like in the Xcode console) the events that are being sent to the app delegate's root view controller? I want to see what if any events I am not forwarding correctly. Does this require me to subclass `UIWindow` and implement `-(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event` where I do something like `NSLog(event)`?

**Edit:** I eventually solved my problem by subclassing UISplitViewController and forcing the delegate method to be called. I wrote a [blog](http://objectiveseesharp.wordpress.com/2013/01/20/uisplitviewcontroller-inside-uitabbarcontroller-in-ios6/) article detailing my solution. However, I still haven't found a good way to determine all the events getting sent to the root view controller.